# DOMPDF reformats HTML look (CodeIgniter library)

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, dompdf

I'm just wondering if there's any other html2pdf CI library that's better than dompdf? I recently converted an excel file to an HTML file and it worked great. But when I tried converting it to PDF, the borders and font were messed up. Anyone can help me please? Here are the links of the screenshots. [Excel to HTML file](http://imgur.com/ksPtZJI,02YsJLB#0), [HTML to PDF file](http://imgur.com/ksPtZJI,02YsJLB#1)

Answer (score 0):

Update: I just updated my dompdf from [this link](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf) and the major problems (i.e. missing borders) were fixed. Though I still needed to download .ufm formats of fonts. And I still need to fix the css of the HTML to be converted like in this [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kV4AQ.jpg)

Comment: It's okay now sir, I'll just fix the css of the output. Thanks! :)